# How to get a starting and ending reservation date for a group in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, date

I have a database called `global` and in that database I have `groups` table and `reservations` table, and the relation is one to many (one group can have many reservations).
What I wanted to do was to display the group name along with the first check in date and the last check out date of the reservations.
I am developing using codeigniter 3.x.

Comment: Hi @Fraol Berhane,welcome to SO, you should give us a lot more details. For example: 
- show us a table construction (columns of the tables we need to use so we can help)
- show us some data (for example you show us data from two tables and a result data you wish to get)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this structure of tables:

```
GROUPS
+--------+-----------+
| id     | Name      | 
+--------+-----------+
```

and:

```
RESERVATIONS
+--------+-----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| id     | Groupid   |  ReservationCheckinDate      |   ReservationCheckoutDate    |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

the SQL to get the desired result would be:

```
SELECT MIN(ReservationCheckinDate), MAX(ReservationCheckoutDate), Name FROM RESERVATIONS
JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.id = RESERVATIONS.Groupid
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

hope it helps